# using re to split string and keep substring contained inside apostrophes grouped together

Tags: python, string, split

```
out = ("First Name,Last Name,Street Address,City,State,Zip Code",",")
```

I am trying to use re to split the string out into the following:

```
['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Street Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code']
```

my output is:

```
['First', 'Name', 'Last', 'Name', 'Street', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Code']
```

How can I split the string and keep any substring contained inside  apostrophes grouped together.

I have very little experience using re so any help would be great.
Thanks.

my code:

```
import re

def split_string(source, splitlist):

    """

    :param source:
    :param splitlist:
    """
    splitlist= re.findall("[\w]+|[*]",source)

    return splitlist
```

Comment: Are you splitting on a comma?

Comment: Post your code.  At the moment your question reads like "please solve my homework problem for me", but if you show what you've done then people might be more willing to help.

Comment: It is not homework, it is part of the udacity online course . I started programming a few weeks ago through MIT course on EDX, the main reason I posted the question is that I find  figuring out when the use of  string.split method or using re is more appropriate quite confusing

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `str.split()` here:

```
In [41]: out = ("First Name,Last Name,Street Address,City,State,Zip Code",",")

In [42]: for x in out:
   ....:     if x.replace(",",""):      #check if the string is not empty
   ....:         print x.split(",")
   ....:         
['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Street Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code']
```

using `re.split()`:

```
In [10]: strs='First Name,Last Name,Street Address,City,State,Zip Code'

In [11]: re.split(r',',strs)
Out[11]: ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Street Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code']
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I am supposed to do this without using sting.split.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've added that too, it' exactly same as `str.split()` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini, is the difference between the .split method and re, simply that re can take multiple args and .split only takes one?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just use `out.split(",")` instead of re? Unless it's for a specific exercise...

Comment: yes in the exercise it asks to achieve this without using the string.split method.